# Dataframe Time to Date time

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime-format

I have a column in a dataframe that has a mix of dates and time.
The column is of type object I would like for each row to have the complete Date not just time.
As you can see the top is the latest time for that date as you go down the list it is just time until a date change then the times below it are for that date until you reach the previous date and it repeats till end of list. Once converted every row should have MMM-DD-YY hh:mm(am/pm) thank you in advance.

sample data below

Datetime

- Apr-23-20 08:20AM
- 07:40AM
- 07:26AM
- 07:25AM
- 06:38AM
- 06:00AM
- 05:25AM
- 02:55AM
- Apr-22-20 08:37PM
- 06:39PM
- 05:00PM
- 04:16PM
- 03:34PM
- 03:08PM
- 12:37PM
- Apr-21-20 09:31PM
- 08:00PM
- 07:27PM
- 06:25PM
- 04:21PM
- 04:08PM
- 02:15PM
- 02:09PM

Sorry I could not find a way to add this in the comment section. But the function looks like this

The code doe not error. Creates new Datetime2 column but does not apply your change on the last line  df['col'] = pd.Series(x)

```
def get_news2(ticker):
"""
Returns a list of sets containing news headline and url

:param ticker: stock symbol
:return: list
"""
ticker = 'AAPL'
NEWS_URL = 'https://finviz.com/news.ashx'
STOCK_URL = 'https://finviz.com/quote.ashx'
page_parsed, _ = http_request_get(url=STOCK_URL, payload={'t': ticker}, parse=True)
table = page_parsed.cssselect('table[class="fullview-news-outer"]')[0]
all_news = page_parsed.cssselect('a[class="tab-link-news"]')
headers = ['Datetime', 'Description', 'Space', 'Source']
urls = [row.get('href') for row in all_news] 
data = [dict(zip(headers, row.xpath('td//text()'))) for row in table[0:]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(urls) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data) 
mergedDf = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
mergedDf = mergedDf.rename(columns={0: "url"})
mergedDf = mergedDf.drop(['Space'], axis=1)
mergedDf['ticker'] = ticker
x = mergedDf['Datetime'].str.split(' ').to_list()  
for i, item in enumerate(x): 
    if len(item) == 2: 
        tem = item[0] 
        x[i] = ' '.join(item) 
else: 
    x[i] = ' '.join([tem, item[0]]) 
mergedDf['Datetime2'] = pd.Series(x)
return mergedDf
```

Comment: Do you actually want the values to be `datetime.datetime` objects or just `str` objects in the noted format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach

```
x = df['col'].str.split(' ').to_list()  
for i, item in enumerate(x): 
    if len(item) == 2: 
        tem = item[0] 
        x[i] = ' '.join(item) 
    else: 
        x[i] = ' '.join([tem, item[0]]) 

df['col'] = pd.Series(x)
```

Comment: Ok so the code works fine as if I run it on its own. no problem. If I place the code inside a function it does not work.

Comment: @LeoTorres Did u place `else` in the right position? what's the error?

Comment: Sorry fell asleep. Like i said no error. it creates column it just does not fix the time it stays the same

Comment: @LeoTorres print x along the way to track its changes.

Comment: No you were right I had else in the wrong place. The else needed 1 more indent. I hate the python indentation. Works now thank you!